# Diagonalization of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is there a method to diagonalize (at least some) $ n \times n $ Vandermonde matrices?

For example invertible matrices which has method to invert them with Cramer method for example, but there is some cases which is not invertible.

Comment: Hi! Actually this is a very hard post to read. The main reasons are because you've used three conjunctions in a single sentence, and the digression about invertibility is a little distracting. Is your question simply "Is there a method to diagonalize (at least some) Vandermonde matrices?"

Comment: Yes, of course.  ;-)

Comment: I edited the first sentence rather heavily to reflect that. If you disagree with the change very strongly, please feel free to change it back by editing. Let me know if you need help with that. I can revert the change myself, if you request.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I don't speak well english, i'm from a foreign country.  :)

Comment: The Vandermonde matrix $V(x_1,\dots x_n)$ is regular *iff* all $x_i$ are distinct

Comment: The Vandermonde matrix is a basis change matrix in the space of polynomials, from the basis of monomials to the basis of Lagrange polynomials, where the dual basis consists of point evaluations. So it is not very natural to ask for a diagonalization. But efficient algorithms exist for multi-point evaluation and interpolation.

Comment: @LutzL That's interesting...

Comment: The algorithms in question can be found under the name "Telegens principle" and also the later paper that states that the reference to "Telegen" is ill-advised.

Comment: WolframAlpha returns diagonalizations for general $2\times 2$ matrices and $3\times 3$ matrices, but of course that isn't a general answer...

Comment: Given that the determinant is simple, I'm a little surprised at how messy the eigenvalues are. None of my searches turned up little about Vandermonde eigenvalues or diagonalization...

Comment: That is because interpreting the V matrix as an automorphism from the base of monomials to the base of monomial results in the map that for a polynomial $p(x)$ computes the image polynomial $(Vp)(x)=p(x_1)+p(x_2)x+\dots+p(x_n)x^{n-1}$. One should expect strange eigenvalues and eigenvectors.